# Separated frontend and backend - how to request authenticated data for server side rendering

Tags: nestjs

Let's say I am serving my frontend on myapplication.com and the backend on api.myapplication.com. The webclient and the mobile app can authenticate against the backend and request data (using JWT).

I would like to enable server side rendering for the webclient. Therefore, the frontend needs to perform authenticated calls to the backend on behalf of the current user. I am considering an oauth-based flow so the frontend has it's own JWT or just sharing the users JWT with the frontend. What are your thoughts on this and do you see major downsides of either way?